# Tell matlab plot to use different number base system

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I am using a vector `t = [YYYYMM]`, which contains my date, and I'm plotting it against a vector x: `plot(t,x)`;
My problem is, how do I adjust the scaling of my x-Axis so that there aren't 100 values between 199402 and 199502, but instead just 12?
I have tried using XTick, with no success, and replaced t with `[1:size(t)]`, and then format everything using

```
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', labels)
```

This produces an off scale, for reasons I don't fully understand.

I have looked into the `dateticks()` option, but wouldn't know to implement it in my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to set the `XTick` to `1:size(t)` because the ticks positions are relative to the `XData`, in your case the *values* of `t`. Instead you want to set the `XTick` to 12 elements from `t` itself.

```
plot(t,x)

%// New tick locations
newticks = t(round(linspace(1, numel(t), 12));

set(gca, 'XTick', newticks)

%// If you want to reset to using all ticks again
set(gca, 'XTick', t)
```

The labels should automatically update when you do this.

Comment: Thank you! I phrased this poorly, I did not set xTick to 1:size(t), i replaced t in the plot with [1:size(t)].

Comment: Update: I found what I was doing wrong because of your answer. My final solution was to not use the vector t, but instead [1:sizeof(t)] and manually set XTick and XTickLabel. Not a beautiful solution but it works.